# python: code optimisation by precalculation of constant therms

Tags: python, math, optimization, code-analysis, precompile

I write a flexible simulation program. Flexibe because the user should be able to customize calculations via python code. 
For customisation he begins with defining some "constants" (constants in the sense that they can never change the value). Then he can use the constants and a few known predefined variables to define the python calculation code. This code is later processed in fixed program code. Here a simplified example:

```
# begin user input
WIDTH = 20.0  # user defined constants
COND = 10.0
calc_code = "COND*WIDTH*x"  # x is a known changing Variable
# end user input

# begin hidden fixed program code
code = compile(
'''
def calc(x):  # function that executes the user code
    return ''' + calc_code  
, '<string>', 'exec') 
exec(code)  # for python 2.x remove brackets

for x in range(10):
    print(calc(x))  # for python 2.x remove brackets
# end hidden fixed program code
```

The problem is that the user code is executed very often and slows down the calculation significantly. Is it possible to somehow automaticaly find and precalculate the constant terms in the code (COND*WIDTH) for a significant speedup?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but no, there's no built-in way. You need to write a program to do this.

Comment: when you start it could you not save a variable y=WIDTH*COND and then just access that variable whenever you need to updated calc_code? That would reduce the number of things that get multiplied

Comment: @TallPaul: this is not possible because the user loose the flexibility and clarity of his input

Comment: @user2303141 Sorry I must have misread the above part, I thought that the user defined those two values and they would not really change at all through the program

Comment: @TallPaul: You understood correctly, the values never change. But the example therm is very simple. In reality the user therms are very complex. It would be hard work to manualy bracket and calculate the constant therms. because of this I need an automatic routine that relieve the strain on the user.

Comment: For a significant speedup? I doubt it. Saving a few multiplies per iteration will probably not help you much. Have you tried manually entering optimized and unoptimized expressions and seeing how much the optimization helps?